# Trying to navigate view controllers using segmented view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a view controller with a segmented control in it. I want to change view controllers using the segmented control. I feel like I'm close, but the view isn't loading when I test my implementation. I added haptic feedback in the viewDidLoad as a test and I feel the feedback when I use the segmented control.

Here is my View Controller Code:

```css
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var content: UIViewController?
          
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(changeView1), name: NSNotification.Name("notifyButtonPressed0"), object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(changeView2), name: NSNotification.Name("notifyButtonPressed1"), object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(changeView3), name: NSNotification.Name("notifyButtonPressed2"), object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(changeView4), name: NSNotification.Name("notifyButtonPressed3"), object: nil)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func setContent(_content: UIViewController?) {

        if (self.content != nil)
    {
        self.content?.view.removeFromSuperview()
        content?.removeFromParentViewController()
    }

    let _content = content
        self.addChildViewController(_content!)
        content?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        self.view.addSubview((content?.view)!)
        
}

    @objc func changeView1(_ kMIDIMessageSendErr: Any?) {
    
    
    
    let storyboardName = "Main"
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
    let vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "View1")
    
    self.content = vc
    
    self.content?.view.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 65, width: 300, height: 450)
    
    }

    @objc func changeView2(_ kMIDIMessageSendErr: Any?) {
    
    
    
    let storyboardName = "Main"
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
    let vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "View2")
    
    self.content = vc
    
    self.content?.view.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 65, width: 300, height: 450)
    
    }
    @objc func changeView3(_ kMIDIMessageSendErr: Any?) {
    
    
    
    let storyboardName = "Main"
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
    let vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "View3")
    
    self.content = vc
    
    self.content?.view.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 65, width: 300, height: 450)
    
    }
    @objc func changeView4(_ kMIDIMessageSendErr: Any?) {
    
    
    
    let storyboardName = "Main"
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
    let vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "View4")
    
    self.content = vc
    
    self.content?.view.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 65, width: 300, height: 450)
    
    }
    
    
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

}
```

Here is my NSObject class I added to my view controller via Interface Builder.

```css
import UIKit

class ButtonHandler: NSObject {
    var segmentControl: UISegmentedControl?


    @IBAction func handleButton1(_ sender: Any) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("notifyButtonPressed"), object: self)
    }
    
    @IBAction func segmentChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        segmentControl = sender
        
        switch segmentControl?.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("notifyButtonPressed0"), object: self)
        case 1:
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("notifyButtonPressed1"), object: self)
        case 2:
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("notifyButtonPressed2"), object: self)
        case 3:
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("notifyButtonPressed3"), object: self)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem lies in my ViewController code but I can't figure out why it's not displaying my view controller. ViewDidLoad gets run but I don't see anything.

EDIT: I converted a function that works in Objective-C to Swift. Maybe you can double check me if I went wrong here.

```css
-(void)setContent:(UIViewController *)content
if(_content)
{
    [_content.view removeFromSuperview];
    [_content removeFromParentViewController];

}

_content = content;
[self addChildViewController:_content];
[content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:_content.view];
}
```

Comment: Do you get some kind of error ?
What is this func? -> func setContent(_content: UIViewController?), it is never called?

Comment: I don't get any errors when compiling but it doesn't work as intended. That function was converted from Objective-C where I think it all fell apart. I put it above in my post. Basically the function is supposed to set the content inside the root view. It first checks if there is existing content (when switching segments) and then removes it. Then, the new content is added and displayed.